# CSS/HTML: Change value of text and expand from center on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure how to accomplish this but need to change the actual TEXT of a p on hover - either transition to a separate p or div altogether or change the text value.

I need to change it to a longer string and would like to "grow" or expand into this longer text on hover from the center of the string and back when the mouse is no longer on the div. How can I do this? Can I use CSS?

Comment: You can't really use CSS (which is for styling web pages) to change your content. This will require JavaScript.

Comment: @TylerH A dirty hack using `::before` or `::after` might be possible though.

Comment: @Siguza I had written up a longer comment describing how it might be possible to hack it but decided against suggesting a bad-practice solution and just stuck with "Use JS" instead. :-) Plus it'd be an extra headache to do that with the animations OP wants.

Comment: Sometimes using CSS for this is ok like for an [On/Off switch](https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/), but in this particular case I would recommend JS like [@TylerH](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2756409/tylerh) said.

Comment: How would this be accomplished best using JS?

Answer (score 0):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#c7c341cc65302aebaca1c9f89d91b726

> I'm not sure how to accomplish this but need to change the actual TEXT of a p on hover...

The ONLY way you can do this in Pure CSS is by using the CSS <kbd>[`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)</kbd> property.

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}
.change-content {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.48em 1em;
}
.change-content:after {
  content: 'Hello';
}
.change-content:hover:after {
  content: 'World';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.1.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="change-content"></button>
```